# Is there a cache in ansible git module?

Tags: git, caching, docker, ansible

I am using an ansible-playbook for my deployment and am using git to checkout my source code. The problem I am having is, I keep on getting stale versions of my source. I don't know why this is happening. It was okay before this. Is there a way to disable the cache is there is one ?

```
- name: Checkout eclaim_revamp source code
  git: repo={{ deployment_url }} dest=/opt/eclaim_revamp force=yes version={{ eclaim_branch }} key_file=~/.ssh/id_travis accept_hostkey=yes
  when: app_version == "eclaim_revamp"
```

Above is the declaration that I use to checkout my source code from bitbucket. Any help would be appreciated.

**More information**

I am running this playbook against a docker image I created.

Comment: Can you include the process you use to run ansible against your docker image? Depending on how you are trying to do this, you may be pushing a change to an immutable and seeing it revert to the original image when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [ansible git module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) should force the checkout (when using `force=yes`), stale files could be the result of a running process keeping an handle on files which should have been updated.

Check if that is the case, or if you see any error message.

---

From the Travis job (which fails), I can see:

```
TASK [app_server : Checkout eclaim source code] ********************************

task path: /root/django_deployment/django_app_server_db_server/deployment/roles/app_server/tasks/main.yml:122

skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}
```

It might be fixed in [issue 14438](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14438#issuecomment-217688181) (and Ansible 2.1)

But in this case, this is simpler: the [Low Kian Seong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501800/low-kian-seong) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008462/is-there-a-cache-in-ansible-git-module/38008989?noredirect=1#comment63492444_38008989):

> I am over-writing one of my own files!

So the checkout works fine, but some files get re-written.

Comment: I uncommented the `force=yes` and my files are still outdated. I run this against a docker based instance and when I ssh into it and check my files are still not updated.

Comment: Yes, if there is a process keeping an handle on a file, force will be ignored because it won't manage to update said file. Could you try and delete completely the git repository, and then try again the mandible git clone/checkout?

Comment: same thing. Could a problem in my git tree cause a behavior like this ?

Comment: If you were able to delete the repo, then it is unlikely to be a process issue.

Comment: Only happens in the docker instance using docker. When I checkout manually into my local file the files are correctly checked out with the latest changes.

Comment: It's even failing in my travis build: https://travis-ci.org/censof/ansible-deployment/builds/139960209

Comment: @LowKianSeong What version of Ansible is Travis using? I have edited the answer.

Comment: My version is 2.0.0.2, but how does a role skipped cause this behavior ? Actually in my playbook there is a task to delete first the source then another task to checkout the source again. This is the link to my playbook: https://github.com/censof/ansible-deployment

Comment: Okay nvm, I figured my own error out. I am over writing one of my own files! Thank you for the trouble for trying to figure this thing out with me. Thank you!

Comment: @LowKianSeong Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.